# Double sum formula for summing over all diagonals

Tags: matrices, summation

I'm solving a problem regarding Newtonian forces. Since $F_{ij}=-F_{ji}$ then $\sum_j m_j\ddot{x}_j=0$. For a demonstration I was thinking to arrange all the $F_{ij}$ as a Matrix $F\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$, including $F_{jj}=0$. If I could express the sum of all elements in such a matrix, as the sum of the diagonals
 $$F_{11}+(F_{12}+F_{21})+(F_{13}+F_{22}+F_{31})+\cdots+(F_{N\ N-1}+F_{N-1\ N})+F_{NN}$$ then the result follows immediately as each ($\cdots$) is zero.

Is there a formula to express $\sum_j\sum_i F_{ij}$ as exactly the sum above? I mean expressing as double sum or similar. Notice that each ($\cdots$) it's exactly the sum of all terms $F_{ij}$ such that $i+j=k$ for $k=2, \cdots, 2N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We  sum up the elements of the matrix $(F_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq N}$ by summing up  the elements of the lower triangle matrix (marked $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$), the main diagonal and the upper   triangle   matrix (marked $\color{red}{\text{red}}$).

We obtain
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{F_{1,1}+\left(F_{1,2}+F_{2,1}\right)+\left(F_{1,3}+F_{2,2}+F_{3,1}\right)}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{+\cdots}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{+\left(F_{1,N-1}+F_{2,N-2}+\cdots+F_{N-1,1}\right)}\\
&\qquad+F_{1,N}+F_{2,N-1}+\cdots+F_{N-1,2}+F_{N,1}\\
&\qquad\color{red}{+\left(F_{2,N}+F_{3,N-1}+\cdots+F_{N,2}\right)}\\
&\qquad\color{red}{+\cdots}\\
&\qquad\color{red}{+\left(F_{N-2,N}+F_{N-1,N-1}+F_{N,N-2}\right)+\left(F_{N-1,N}+F_{N,N-1}\right)+F_{N,N}}\\
&\,\,=\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\sum_{l=1}^{k}F_{l,k+1-l}}+\sum_{l=1}^{N}F_{l,N+1-l}+\color{red}{\sum_{k=2}^N\sum_{l=k}^NF_{l,N+k-l}}
\end{align*}